Python. Telebot. Реагирование на введённое слово
Есть код:
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if message.text == "↩️Назад":
        ...

Все слова, а так же команды, наподобие /start и тд, перехватываются этим декоратором.
Можно ли сделать реагирование только на выражение "↩️Назад"?
Вариант - перенести этот кусок кода в конец не подходят.

Воспользуйтесь lambda функцией, а дальше придумайте любое подходящее вам условие которое вернёт True:
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: "назад" in message.text.lower())

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: "назад" == message.text.lower())

